# I am getting error as "System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'" while deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

I am trying to parse Large XML response coming from API into C# objects using XML deserialization but getting errors as System.ArgumentException: 'illegal characters in path' [image: this screenshot gives much detail about the error]

The code I tried is below

```
// XML Response from API is stored in xml variable
string xml = Response.Content;
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AmazonEnvelope));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(xml);
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
AmazonEnvelope XmlData = (AmazonEnvelope)obj;
reader.Close();
```

Classes based on XML response the Classes are created below so as to deserialize.

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header")]
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DocumentVersion")]
        public string DocumentVersion { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Address")]
    public class Address
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostalCode")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FulfillmentData")]
    public class FulfillmentData
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FulfillmentChannel")]
        public string FulfillmentChannel { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShipServiceLevel")]
        public string ShipServiceLevel { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Amount")]
    public class Amount
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Component")]
    public class Component
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Amount")]
        public Amount Amount { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemPrice")]
    public class ItemPrice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Component")]
        public List<Component> Component { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Promotion")]
    public class Promotion
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PromotionIDs")]
        public string PromotionIDs { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShipPromotionDiscount")]
        public string ShipPromotionDiscount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemPromotionDiscount")]
        public string ItemPromotionDiscount { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrderItem")]
    public class OrderItem
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AmazonOrderItemCode")]
        public string AmazonOrderItemCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ASIN")]
        public string ASIN { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SKU")]
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemStatus")]
        public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProductName")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Quantity")]
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemPrice")]
        public ItemPrice ItemPrice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Promotion")]
        public Promotion Promotion { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumberOfItems")]
        public string NumberOfItems { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PriceDesignation")]
        public string PriceDesignation { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Order")]
    public class Order
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AmazonOrderID")]
        public string AmazonOrderID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MerchantOrderID")]
        public string MerchantOrderID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PurchaseDate")]
        public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LastUpdatedDate")]
        public string LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OrderStatus")]
        public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SalesChannel")]
        public string SalesChannel { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FulfillmentData")]
        public FulfillmentData FulfillmentData { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsBusinessOrder")]
        public string IsBusinessOrder { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsSoldByAB")]
        public string IsSoldByAB { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OrderItem")]
        public List<OrderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FulfilledBy")]
        public string FulfilledBy { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Message")]
    public class Message
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Order")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AmazonEnvelope")]
    public class AmazonEnvelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MessageType")]
        public string MessageType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Message")]
        public List<Message> Message { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string NoNamespaceSchemaLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

The XML response from the API is Below.

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"amzn-envelope.xsd\">\r\n<Header>\r\n <DocumentVersion>1.00</DocumentVersion>\r\n </Header>\r\n<MessageType>AllOrdersReport</MessageType>\r\n<Message>\r\n   <Order>\r\n      <AmazonOrderID>407-4867592-2717133</AmazonOrderID>\r\n      <MerchantOrderID>407-4867592-2717133</MerchantOrderID>\r\n      <PurchaseDate>2021-01-03T18:29:44+00:00</PurchaseDate>\r\n      <LastUpdatedDate>2021-01-05T08:03:11+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>\r\n      <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>\r\n      <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>\r\n      <FulfillmentData>\r\n         <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>\r\n         <ShipServiceLevel>Expedited</ShipServiceLevel>\r\n         <Address>\r\n            <City>PATNA</City>\r\n            <State>BIHAR</State>\r\n            <PostalCode>800020</PostalCode>\r\n            <Country>IN</Country>\r\n         </Address>\r\n     </FulfillmentData>\r\n     <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>\r\n     <IsSoldByAB>false</IsSoldByAB>\r\n     <OrderItem>\r\n        <AmazonOrderItemCode>65393459928915</AmazonOrderItemCode>\r\n        <ASIN>B07GMRJTS9</ASIN>\r\n        <SKU>CT4G4DFS8266-01</SKU>\r\n        <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>\r\n        <ProductName>Crucial RAM 4GB DDR4 2666 MHz CL19 Desktop Memory CT4G4DFS8266</ProductName>\r\n        <Quantity>1</Quantity>\r\n        <ItemPrice>\r\n           <Component>\r\n              <Type>Principal</Type>\r\n              <Amount currency=\"INR\">1450.0</Amount>\r\n           </Component>\r\n           <Component>\r\n              <Type>Shipping</Type>\r\n              <Amount currency=\"INR\">40.0</Amount>\r\n           </Component>\r\n        </ItemPrice>\r\n        <Promotion>\r\n          <PromotionIDs>IN Core Free Shipping 2015/04/08 23-48-5-108</PromotionIDs>\r\n           <ShipPromotionDiscount>40.0</ShipPromotionDiscount>\r\n        </Promotion>\r\n     </OrderItem>\r\n  </Order>\r\n</Message>\r\n<Message>\r\n   <Order>\r\n      <AmazonOrderID>408-5979374-7689108</AmazonOrderID>\r\n      <MerchantOrderID>408-5979374-7689108</MerchantOrderID>\r\n      <PurchaseDate>2021-01-03T18:29:31+00:00</PurchaseDate>\r\n      <LastUpdatedDate>2021-01-04T05:33:41+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>\r\n      <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>\r\n      <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>\r\n      <FulfillmentData>\r\n         <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>\r\n         <ShipServiceLevel>Expedited</ShipServiceLevel>\r\n         <Address>\r\n            <City>bangalore</City>\r\n            <State>KARNATAKA</State>\r\n            <PostalCode>560013</PostalCode>\r\n            <Country>IN</Country>\r\n         </Address>\r\n     </FulfillmentData>\r\n     <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>\r\n     <IsSoldByAB>false</IsSoldByAB>\r\n     <OrderItem>\r\n        <AmazonOrderItemCode>15137904364451</AmazonOrderItemCode>\r\n        <ASIN>B01KVHE7Q4</ASIN>\r\n        <SKU>LHOBT6C2101-20</SKU>\r\n        <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>\r\n        <ProductName>Lapcare CQ42 6-Cell Battery for HP Laptops</ProductName>\r\n        <Quantity>1</Quantity>\r\n        <ItemPrice>\r\n           <Component>\r\n              <Type>Principal</Type>\r\n              <Amount currency=\"INR\">1474.0</Amount>\r\n           </Component>\r\n        </ItemPrice>\r\n        <Promotion>\r\n          <PromotionIDs>IN Core Free Shipping 2015/04/08 23-48-5-108</PromotionIDs>\r\n        </Promotion>\r\n     </OrderItem>\r\n  </Order>\r\n</Message>\r\n<Message>\r\n   <Order>\r\n      <AmazonOrderID>402-6447122-2319519</AmazonOrderID>\r\n      <PurchaseDate>2021-01-02T10:38:25+00:00</PurchaseDate>\r\n      <LastUpdatedDate>2021-01-02T10:56:16+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>\r\n      <OrderStatus>Cancelled</OrderStatus>\r\n      <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>\r\n      <FulfillmentData>\r\n         <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>\r\n         <ShipServiceLevel>Standard</ShipServiceLevel>\r\n         <Address>\r\n            <City>UDAIPUR</City>\r\n            <State>RAJASTHAN</State>\r\n            <PostalCode>313002</PostalCode>\r\n            <Country>IN</Country>\r\n         </Address>\r\n     </FulfillmentData>\r\n     <FulfilledBy>Easy Ship</FulfilledBy>\r\n     <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>\r\n     <IsSoldByAB>false</IsSoldByAB>\r\n     <OrderItem>\r\n        <AmazonOrderItemCode>64569408711947</AmazonOrderItemCode>\r\n        <ASIN>B07K1XZXJL</ASIN>\r\n        <SKU>U0H96E</SKU>\r\n            <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>\r\n        <ProductName>HP Care Pack 1 Year Accidental Damage Protection ADP with Onsite Support Add-on Pack for Pavilion and X360 Laptops</ProductName>\r\n        <Quantity>0</Quantity>\r\n     </OrderItem>\r\n     <OrderItem>\r\n        <AmazonOrderItemCode>68114446086235</AmazonOrderItemCode>\r\n        <ASIN>B001B2U5R4</ASIN>\r\n        <SKU>U0H91E</SKU>\r\n            <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>\r\n        <ProductName>HP Care Pack 2 Years Additional Warranty Next Business Day Support and Onsite Service for HP Omen &amp; Envy Laptop</ProductName>\r\n        <Quantity>0</Quantity>\r\n     </OrderItem>\r\n  </Order>\r\n</Message>\r\n<Message>\r\n   <Order>\r\n      <AmazonOrderID>406-0676704-1460352</AmazonOrderID>\r\n      <MerchantOrderID>406-0676704-1460352</MerchantOrderID>\r\n      <PurchaseDate>2021-01-01T17:58:26+00:00</PurchaseDate>\r\n      <LastUpdatedDate>2021-01-02T07:27:17+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>\r\n      <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>\r\n      <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>\r\n      <FulfillmentData>\r\n         <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>\r\n         <ShipServiceLevel>Expedited</ShipServiceLevel>\r\n         <Address>\r\n            <City>BENGALURU</City>\r\n            <State>KARNATAKA</State>\r\n            <PostalCode>560051</PostalCode>\r\n            <Country>IN</Country>\r\n         </Address>\r\n     </FulfillmentData>\r\n     <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>\r\n     <IsSoldByAB>false</IsSoldByAB>\r\n     <OrderItem>\r\n        <AmazonOrderItemCode>65883701062139</AmazonOrderItemCode>\r\n        <ASIN>B07Z87LXY1</ASIN>\r\n        <SKU>F4-3600C16D-16GTZRC</SKU>\r\n        <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>\r\n        <ProductName>G.Skill F4-3600C16D-16GTZRC Trident Z RGB DDR4-3600MHz CL16-19-19-39 1.35V 16GB (2x8GB) Memory</ProductName>\r\n        <Quantity>1</Quantity>\r\n        <ItemPrice>\r\n           <Component>\r\n              <Type>Principal</Type>\r\n              <Amount currency=\"INR\">11699.0</Amount>\r\n           </Component>\r\n        </ItemPrice>\r\n     </OrderItem>\r\n     <OrderItem>\r\n        <AmazonOrderItemCode>29991566012307</AmazonOrderItemCode>\r\n        <ASIN>B089XVWVZ9</ASIN>\r\n        <SKU>90MB1490-M0IAY0</SKU>\r\n        <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>\r\n        <ProductName>ASUS TUF Gaming B550M-Plus AM4 PCIe 4.0 DDR4 (4600 O.C.) mATX Motherboard with 2.5Gb Ethernet WiFi 6 2X M.2 USB 3.2 Gen2 and Aura Sync RGB Support</ProductName>\r\n        <Quantity>1</Quantity>\r\n        <ItemPrice>\r\n           <Component>\r\n              <Type>Principal</Type>\r\n              <Amount currency=\"INR\">15940.0</Amount>\r\n           </Component>\r\n        </ItemPrice>\r\n     </OrderItem>\r\n  </Order>\r\n</Message>\r\n</AmazonEnvelope>\r\n"
```

Please help

Comment: The StreamReader constructor accepts the path as input, but not the xml-content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XmlTextReader`

```
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
    {
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        AmazonEnvelope XmlData = (AmazonEnvelope)obj;
    }
}
```